# using perl, how to select last 2 lines in the case of each row has same word?

Tags: arrays, perl

```
Bini  --  -21.89753  -20.47853  -20.27835  -18.34952  -16.23454

Bini  --  -16.89753  -14.47853  -13.27835  -12.34952  -11.23454

Bini  --  -10.09014
```

my file has an array as shown above. 
And this array starting with Bini is array having multilines but I am showing only 3 lines here.
What I wanted to try is to extract last 3 elements from the last 2 lines.
So, -12.34952  -11.23454 -10.09014  these 3 elements were that I wanted.
Sometimes, last line may have elments from 2 to 5 depending on the files. But here, it has only 1 elements from the last line.

What I tried was as follows

```
while(my $line = <FILE>) {
     if($line =~ /Bini/) {      #extract last 3, 2, 1 element
     my @entries = split(/Ws+/,$line);
     $element1 = (pop@entries);
     $element2 = (pop@entries);
     $element3 = (pop@entries);
     }
```

As a result, I could see element1 which is -10.09014, but unfortunately, I couldn't get element 2 and element 3.
Could anybody help me? ..

---

I want to keep my original script. I mean,, creaing process of result.txt and opening method of "log" which is output format.

> Blockquote

```
#!/usr/bin/perl use warnings; 
use strict; 
use File::stat; 

open (OUT, ">", "result\.txt") or die "cannot open file\,\n"; #from this plx, I want to creat result.txt 

foreach my $answer (glob "*.log") { # format of reading file will be "log" 

open (FILE, "<", "$answer") or die "Cannot open file\.\n"; 
my @file = split ('\.', $answer);
```

> Blockquote

your opening method of file induced error ( my @array = read_file('input.txt')
I wonder how can I do using script starting from my $line = 0 from your script.
Even though I changed format of txt to log (e.g. input.log), it still gave error message.
(read_file 'input.txt' - sysopen: No such file or directory at text.plx line 6)

.....

Comment: Please show how you print out the elements. I think you might have an error there. Also do you really split on `/Ws+/`? This matches `Wsss` etc. Don't you mean `/\s+/`?

Comment: Can you show clearly the desired output?

Comment: Why "the last two lines" and why "the last three elements"? Do you just always want the last three elements, regardless of how many lines? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take all numbers from every line, push them at the end of `@entries`, and always keep only last three.

```
my @entries;
while(my $line = <FILE>) {
     next if $line !~ /Bini/;
     push @entries, grep /\d/, split /\s+/,$line;
     @entries = @entries[-3 .. -1] if @entries > 3;
}
print join "\n", @entries;
```

output

```
-12.34952
-11.23454
-10.09014
```

Comment: This was working for me. Thanks very much. if it is possible, could you explain what is the meaning of variable of entries are larger than 3... As a result of pusing, expected array is like (elment 1, element 2, elment 3, element 4) under entries >3 ? if I use entries >2 what will be happen?.....

Comment: @user2743610 it could be also written as `if (@entries > 3) { @entries = @entries[-3 .. -1]; }` If you use `@entries >2` **and** `@entries[-2 .. -1]` then you'll get only last two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

••• NOTE •••• The input file here is specific to your more recent, blocked, question ([using perl, how to select last 2 lines in the case of each row has same word?(re-questioned..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640243/using-perl-how-to-select-last-2-lines-in-the-case-of-each-row-has-same-wordre)) and as such will only work with that input.

This is the input you recently provided:

```
Bini  --  -10.09014  

cidi

Bini  --  -21.89753  -21.47853  -20.27835  -20.34952  -17.23454

Bini  --  -16.89753  -12.47853  -11.27835  -11.34952  -10.23454

Bini  --  -09.09014  

light is 3.4
```

This will achieve exactly what you want (i.e. extract the last two elements from the second-to-last line starting with 'Bini' and the last element from the last line ending in 'Bini') , but no more ...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = 'location/of/your/file.txt';
open my $input, '<', $file or die "Can't write to $file: $!";

my $line = 0;
my (@element1, @element2, @element3);
while (<$input>){ 
    chomp;
    next if ($_ =~ /^\s*$/); # skips a line of input if the line is blank
        if ($_ =~ /^Bini/) { # if the line starts with Bini
            $line++; # Add 1 to count variable
            my @split = split('\s+'); # split by spaces
            if ($line == 3) { # if the line number = 3 (i.e. second to last)
                push @element1, $split[-1]; # add the last element of split (-10.234...) to @element1
                push @element2, $split[-2]; # # add the second-to-last element of split to @element2
            }
            elsif ($line == 4) { # if the line number is 4 (last line starting with Bini
                push @element3, $split[-1]; # # add the last element of split to @element1
            }
        }
}

print "$element3[0]\t$element1[0]\t$element2[0]\n";
```

Output:

```
-09.09014   -10.23454   -11.34952
```

Comment: If this works then please select it as your answer, and let's all move on from this...

Comment: I coudnt try right now since my labtop is window based. I will try within 2days . The number of element for last line could be one or two or even five depending on output file. I hope this wiill work for every case.

Comment: Also line number starting with bini could be multi lines even though it shows only 4lines here

Comment: the code will always extract the last two elements from the second-to-last line starting with 'Bini' and the last element from the last line ending in 'Bini' - no matter how many lines or elements each line has

Comment: could u explain briefly what the each line mean..i couldnt understand exactly yr code.. I am fresh user for perl. Also where should i go to select answer?

Comment: why line number 3 means second to last element? line number means 3rd line from the example? if so, line number will vary depending on output file..also somtimes all three ellements could be in last line. Sorry fot too many qurstions

Comment: error message showed up as follow : read_file 'input.txt' - sysopen: No such file or directory at text.plx line 6

Comment: I would suggest that you spend some time on this site: http://www.perl.com/pub/2000/10/begperl1.html before you go any further. If you don't understand basic perl, and if you're unwilling to put some though into it yourself, it will be very hard for anyone to help you properly

Comment: I will read.. but your script wasn't work. error mesage is ...can't locate File/slurp.pm in @INC (@INC contains: D:/perl/site/lib). My orginal script used stat rather than slurp. Although I should read what you suggest, right now,, I need a solution...

Comment: That's an easy fix. However, it sounds like your requirements keep changing, so my code won't achieve what you want anyway?

Comment: First of all, I thank yr useful advice, But it didn't work for me. I tried a lot but it alwyas gave me error message....But I really appreciate your reply. Two part, my @array = read_file('input.txt') and slurp induced error.

Comment: If you give further solution without error (keeping the stat and opening method of file), I want to select your answer as well.

Comment: I've updated to remove the need for `file::slurp`. All you need to do is save  your input to a file, and change `location/of/your/file.txt` in my code to the actual location of your file and, provided the input is the same as the one I've used, it will work.

Comment: Theres no method to select 2 answers? I couln't do that. If I do that, previous one (green color) disappered.