# using perl, how to select last 2 lines in the case of each row has same word?(re-questioned..)

Tags: arrays, perl

```
Bini  --  -10.09014  

cidi

Bini  --  -21.89753  -21.47853  -20.27835  -20.34952  -17.23454

Bini  --  -16.89753  -12.47853  -11.27835  -11.34952  -10.23454

Bini  --  -09.09014  

light is 3.4
```

my file has an array as shown above. 
What I wanted to try is to extract last 3 elements from the last 2 lines.
So, -12.34952  -11.23454 -10.09014  these 3 elements were that I wanted.
Sometimes, last line may end with 1 element to 5 elements depending on the files. 
But here, it   has only 1 element from the last line. 
So what I want for format was as follow.

name                 H1            H2             H3              H4

file name        -09.09014   -10.23454   -11.34952

H4 will be other element that I want to extract from opened file.
Below is what I did..
Actually, from push, I lost the way. Even I don't know the meaning...
When you give comment, it would be really good to give even short advice.

> Blockquote

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::stat;
open (OUT, ">", "result\.txt") or die "cannot open file\,\n";
printf OUT "      code     H1     H2     H3     H4[A\.U\.]\n";

foreach my $answer (glob "*.log") {        

open (FILE, "<", "$answer") or die "Cannot open file\.\n";               

my @file = split ('\.', $answer);
my $name = $file[0];  
my @entries;    # 

while(my $line = <FILE>) {
      next if $line !~ /Bini/;     # take H1 H2 H3   
      push @entries, grep /\d/, split /\s+/,$line;
}

elsif ($line =~ /light/) {              # take take H4
        @entries_h3 = split(/\s+/,$line);
 $element4 = $entries_h3[3];
}

else {
  next;
  }
 }
}

PRINT:
printf OUT "%10s %12.3f %12.3f %12.3f %12.3f,$name, $element1, $element2, $element3, $element4;
close (FILE);
}
close (OUT);
```

> Blockquote

Mostly, it showed error message as follows:
Global symbol "@entries" requires explicit package name at new.plx ~~
Execution of new.plx aborted due to compilation errors.
Above is just that I combined from the advice...
From the line starting with next if,  it might be corrected.

Could anybody help me? ..  I am desperate...

Comment: Rather than asking the same question twice, it's better to amend/clarify the original question...

Comment: See my answer to your original question. I've provided code which will answer the modified input you provide in this question...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596938/using-perl-how-to-select-last-2-lines-in-the-case-of-each-row-has-same-word